# Copying Google Datastore entries from one Kind to another Kind in same project using Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I am trying to copy some Datastore entries from one Kind to another in Google using Java.

I have some entries in the Kind "Reserve" and now when certain conditions meet, I would like these entries to be copied into a new Kind called "Active".

In the Kind "Reserve", each entries have the following properties such as:

Name, Surname, Timestamp, etc.

My code so far is:

```
if(dataList.contains("UpdateNeeded")) {
            Datastore datastore = DatastoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
            Query<Entity> query =
                    Query.newEntityQueryBuilder().setNamespace("userdata")
                            .setKind("Reserve").build();
            QueryResults<Entity> results = datastore.run(query);
            while (results.hasNext()) {
                Entity itr = results.next();
           // it is here where i need to implement a logic to copy over to another Kind but I dont seem to figure out how.
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy an entity by passing it to a builder.  E.g.

```
Key alteredKey = Key.newBuilder(itr.getKey().getParent(), "Active");
Entity newEntity = Entity.newBuilder(alteredKey, itr);`
```